# How to count the solutions to the system $\left\{\begin{matrix} (x+y)^2+z^2\leq(x+z)^2+y^2 \\ (x+y)^2+z^2\leq(y+z)^2+x^2 \end{matrix}\right.$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality

Recently, I have found this problem:

> Let $x,y,z$ three integers such that $0<x,y,z\leq100$ and $(x+y)^2+z^2$ is a perfect square. Determine all possible solutions to the following system of inequalites: $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
> (x+y)^2+z^2\leq(x+z)^2+y^2
> \\ (x+y)^2+z^2\leq(y+z)^2+x^2
> \end{matrix}\right.$$

To solve this, first, I rewrite the system as: $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
2xy\leq2xz
\\ 2xy\leq2yz
\end{matrix}\right.$$ And so: $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
y\leq z
\\x\leq z
\end{matrix}\right.$$

But here I am stuck because $z$ can vary and I don't have any certainty if for a generic triplet $(x,y,z)$ the expression $(x+y)^2+z^2$ is a perfect square. This is the graph of the trend of the number of such $(x,y,z)$ for $1\leq x,y,z\leq120$:

[image]

Here, you can find the Python code I used for bruteforcing:

```
import math

def is_square(apositiveint):

  x = apositiveint // 2

  seen = set([x])

  while x * x != apositiveint:

    x = (x + (apositiveint // x)) // 2

    if x in seen: return False

    seen.add(x)

  return True

M = 1
S = 0

while (M <= 120):

  for x in range(1,M + 1):

    for y in range(1,M + 1):

      for z in range(1,M + 1):

        if ((x <= y) and (z <= y) and (is_square((x + z) ** 2 + y ** 2)) == True):

          S = S + 1

  print('Number of non-orderd [x,y,z] smaller than ',M,' is: ',S)

  M = M + 1
```

I have also tried to set $(x+y)=b$ and $z=a$ where $a^2+b^2=c^2$ that I can generate using the formulae: $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
a=m^2-n^2
\\b=2mn
\end{matrix}\right.$$with $m,n \in N$.

But also this way seems complicated and no useful. Any idea? 
This is, instead, the graph of the trend of the number of ordered $(x,y,z)$ with $1\leq x,y,z \leq120$:

[image]

Here, instead, you can find the Python code to generate the number of ordered $(x,y,z)$:

```
import math
import itertools

def Solutions(M):

    A=[]

    for m in range(1,M+1):

        for n in range(1,int((M+1)/2)+1):

            if ((math.gcd(m,n) == 1) and (((m % 2 == 0) and (n % 2 == 1)) or ((m % 2 == 1) and (n % 2 == 0)))):

                X=m**2-n**2
                Y=2*m*n

                if((X>0)and(Y>0)):

                    k=2

                    while((Y<=M)and(X<=2*M)):

                        if((X<=2*M)and(Y<=M)):

                            for x in range(1,X):

                                y=X-x

                                if((x<=Y)and(y<=Y)and(x<=M)and(y<=M)and(Y<=M)):

                                    A.append(sorted([x,y,Y]))                   

                        X=(m**2-n**2)*k
                        Y=(2*m*n)*k

                        k=k+1

                    X=m**2-n**2
                    Y=2*m*n

                    k=2

                    while((X<=M)and(Y<=2*M)):

                        if((Y<=2*M)and(X<=M)):

                            for x in range(1,Y):

                                y=Y-x

                                if((x<=M)and(y<=M)and(x<=X)and(y<=X)and(X<=M)):

                                    A.append(sorted([x,y,X]))

                        X=(m**2-n**2)*k
                        Y=(2*m*n)*k

                        k=k+1

    A.sort()

    return len(list(A for A,_ in itertools.groupby(A)))

M = 1

while (M<=120):

    print('Number of orderd [x,y,z] smaller than ',M,' is: ',Solutions(M))

    M = M + 1
```

What can we say about this case: is there a general formulae for counting such $(x,y,z)$? Any idea would be appreciated?

Comment: There are $4033$ in case someone wants to verify his calculations (though I have no idea how to reach that without brute force for now...).

Comment: Some insights : https://justpaste.it/40ipe first column are reachable hypothenuse numbers given limit $x,y,z\le 100$ (https://oeis.org/A009003) second one is number of triplets $(x,y,z)$ satisfying this square and conditions $x\le z, y\le z$. This looks awfully without any pattern...